# trouble querying 2 different lists from a SharePoint welcome page using ECMA

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

My approach is not working here.  I am on a Welcome Page of a SharePoint 2010 document set and have placed my script in a Content Editor Web Part CEWP. I've got a block of jquery/javascript using the following  code.  I can get one or the other set of values from two different blocks of code but not both.  So it seems like my duplicating some of the lines of code in the tow queries causes things to clash but I am not sure what i can change to make both sets unique or what is clashing between the two.  Any guidance greatly appreciated.  I'm just going in circles right now.  thanks  -dave

I am using two blocks that look like this but differ at listName. Maybe the page can only support one of these?

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            async: false,
            CAMLRowLimit: 2000,                
            listName: "Personnel Management",
            completefunc: fnCallBack
        });
    });


    function fnCallBack(xData, Status) {
        var index = 0;
        $documentListtable = $("#documentListtable");
        //Navigate through the XML
        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {


    //Get the values to a local variable
            var _url = $(this).attr("ows_FileRef").split(";#")[1];
            var _name = $(this).attr("ows_LinkFilename");
       ;
            var _author = $(this).attr("ows_Editor").split(";#")[1];
            var modifiedOn = $(this).attr("ows_Modified");
            var _TrainingStatus = $(this).attr("ows_Training_x0020_Certificates");




            //Create clone of the table row
            var $row = $("#templates").find(".row-template").clone();

            //Add values to the column based on the css class

            $row.find(".DocumentName").html(_pdfLink);
            $row.find(".Author").html(_author);
            $row.find(".LastModifiedOn").html(modifiedOn);
            $row.find(".TrainingStatus").html(_TrainingStatus);


            //Change the style for even rows
            if (index % 2 == 0) {
                $row.addClass("jtable-row-even")
            }


     if (_TrainingStatus.indexOf("1001") !=-1)
      {
       index = index + 1;
            //add the row to table
            $documentListtable.append($row);

           }

                    -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding both the SPServices calls inside one  $(document).ready instead of having two  $(document).ready blocks. There can be multiple  $(document).ready in a page but your issue sounds like only one SPService call is triggered on page load.